# Cannot execute JMX MXBean operation of type CompositeData from JConsole

Tags: java, jmx

I have a custom MXBean called JmxJobLauncher that has a managed operation called launchExampleJob with a single parameter this is a complex type.  In jconsole it shows the type as CompositeData and I can see the original type it maps back to (ExampleJobParams) so that all looks good.  The problem is the button to execute the launchExampleJob is grayed out and it doesn't allow me to set any of the CompositeData values for the parameter.  Is this not supported in jconsole?  Is there a jmx console that supports this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's beyond the capabilities of jconsole. From time to time, I implement " jconsole convenience" methods in my MXBeans that either accept loads of string and primitive based parameters, or accept a simple string, which I then recompose back into a target type instance.

As far as jconsole goes, composite types are great for display, but not so much for passing in. If you're in the mood for a bit of jquery, take a look at [jolokia](http://www.jolokia.org/) which is a REST based JMX interface.

Comment: Thanks.  I was guessing maybe that was the case.  I will take a gander at jolokia.